# How can I elegantly synchronize access to an arbitrary buffer?

Tags: c++, concurrency, mutex

I have a buffer that is currently accessed via a pointer to the beginning of the buffer. I'm trying to come up with a way to guarantee nobody can access the buffer unless they hold a lock on it. For example:

```
class Buffer {
  friend class BufferGuard;
  std::mutex mutex;
  void* buffer;
}

struct BufferGuard {
  BufferGuard(Buffer& parent) { parent.mutex.lock() }
  ~BufferGuard() { parent.mutex.unlock(); }

  void* Get() { return parent.buffer; }
}
```

However this is easily defeated by saving the result of `BufferGuard::Get`. This solution, as well as any others I can think of, rely on users of my library being well behaved. Am looking for a solution where misbehaving isn't an option.

Comment: There are more ways to "misbehave" in C++ than there are grains of sand in the ocean. If you want to make it *inconvenient*, you could expose a reference instead. You're basically asking "How can I make it impossible to invoke undefined behaviour" and the answer is "You can't." Once you've handed over the goods there's no stopping them from using that information for whatever purpose.

Comment: Why not make this wrapper more transparent, as in `Buffer` has a `lock()` function which returns a guard, and from there you can access the internals. Good ergonomics mean people have to go out of their way to mis-use it.

Comment: This idea may be of use: https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/issues/924 there is an implementation of it (untested) here: https://github.com/galik/GSL/blob/lockable-objects/include/gsl/gsl_lockable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot guarantee that people cannot break your guard while giving them access to a trivially copyable object like `void*`. However, you can make it more explicitly obvious that the user is doing something wrong:

```
struct BufferGuard {
  private:
    Buffer& parent;
  public:
    BufferGuard(Buffer& parent) : parent{parent} { parent.mutex.lock() }
    ~BufferGuard() { parent.mutex.unlock(); }
    BufferGuard(BufferGuard const&) = delete;
    BufferGuard(BufferGuard&&) = delete;
    BufferGuard& operator=(BufferGuard const&) = delete;
    BufferGuard& operator=(BufferGuard&&) = delete;

  template <std::regular_invocable<void*> Op>
  void operate(Op&& operation) {
    std::forward<Op>(operation)(parent.buffer);
  }
}

void usecase(Buffer& buffer) {
  BufferGuard guard{buffer};
  guard.operate([](void* buf) { new(buf) int{7}; })
}
```

This means, you don't directly return the pointer to use freely; Your user can only do something with the pointer as long as your guard is around. And as long as your guard is around, your lock is alive. Of course, a nifty user will find a way to hoist the pointer value out of the callback, but it takes intent to misuse the interface.

Comment: *it takes intent to misuse the interface* -- Does it really? Stupidity/naiveté may suffice: A naive user (knowing little about asynchronous access and locks) may simply want to keep a copy of `buffer*` to keep doing something with it. To this end, they find a way to get it from your `BufferGuard` (w/o knowning what "guard" really means). Perhaps one should use explicit function names that make it clear that the buffer returned shouldn't be stored for later use ...

Comment: @Walter Yes, true. The `Buffer` from the OP should be non-copyable and non-movable as well and expose its `void*` member only to `BufferGuard`. Which it already does. So there is no way to get to the pointer except through `BufferGuard::operate`. What would be a better name for that member function?